# Skip parsing the BBCode inside the CODE tag

Tags: php, html, regex, bbcode

I'm parsing the BBCode using the `regex` in order to replace it into the HTML. I'm stuck right now because of the `[code]` tags parsing.

Basically, when you do `[code][b]this is bb[/b] [u]code in[/u] [i]code[/i][/code]` it shouldnt replace the `[b]`, `[u]`, `[i]` and similar tags that are INSIDE of the `[code]` tag.

Unfortunately, using the preg_replace:

```
$this->_text = preg_replace('/\[i](.+?)\[\/i]/i', '<em>\1</em>', $this->_text);
$this->_text = preg_replace('/\[code](.+?)\[\/code]]/i', '<code>\1</code>', $this->_text);
```

will cause replacing them all, and the code inside of the `[code]` tag will become HTML formated.

Is there any work-around for this? I need ideas. I was thinking about escaping the `[`, `]` brackets characters in `[code]` before parsing the rest, but this idea sound silly.

Comment: You cannot parse HTML or BBCode with Regular Expressions because HTML and BBCode are not examples of a 'Regular Language'. You need a proper parsing library that exposes the structure of the document to your program where you can then work with it.

Comment: @Dai If that would be HTML, I would surely use the `DOM`. For the basics of BBCode I want to use the regex I dont see the point of using any code-exposing parsing libraries because thats too much (and regex can achieve what I want), at least in my case.

Comment: Your "workaround" is not silly, I don't see another way to do this besides a full parser as @Dai has suggested - which IMHO is the "right way (TM)".

Comment: Just an idea, why not replace square brackets `[]` with angled brackets `<>` and attempt to parse with `DomDocument`, don't know if it'll work :)

Comment: @gwillie That *should* work though it doesn't recognize if the tag name is either correct or not. I like the idea ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, xml parsers don't care about tag names I believe, xml is about structure not about the names/tags you use to identify sections/portions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to parse from the exterior in, you need something like this for your code tag

```
(?:\[code])(.*)(?=(?:\[\/code]))
```

But as other have mentioned, you should be very careful with you do with this because you can not guarantee what is coming to you, it may be malformed and then you will end up with a mess of tags or even an incomplete mixture of parsed and unparsed bbcodes.

Even the code that i just wrote will fail if you have two [/code][/code].